# Assistance with Excel Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, risk

I'm trying to create a formula for conditional formatting that will identify two words and create an output of a word.

See example below:

[image: Excel Cells]

Right now I'm having to manually put in the Risk Type. I want it to output the risk type based on the likelihood and impact.

[image: Risk Chart]

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd create the risk chart as a table and then use index match pairs to find the row and column to locate the result you are seeking.

```
=index(RISK_TABLE_RANGE,MATCH(Likelihood_Cell,Likelihood_Range_RISKTABLE,0),
 MATCH(Risk_Cell,Impact_Range_RISKTABLE,0))
```

Essentially, you have the entire RISK_TABLE as one range and two additional ranges Likelihood_Range and Impact_Range which are the header/index for your risk table. You match on the two ranges and you get the cell coordinates for the RISK Level which appears in the square.

Think of it as a game of battleship where you ask "what row does very unlikely appear" and then "what column does major appear"

Comment: I put in the formula you posted and linked it to my risk table, but it did not place in Risk type after I filled in the Likelihood and Impact columns. Not sure why?

Comment: You need to define three different named ranges:

Comment: You need to define three different named ranges:

1. the entire RISK_TABLE
2. the headers for the Likelihood_Range
3. the headers for the Impact_Range

Comment: Oh wow, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Go into Formulas -> Define Name

Comment: Go into Formulas -> Define Name

In my example the named ranges are called RISK_TABLE Likelihood_Range and Impact_Range  

You can define the areas that they cover and then it should work.

Comment: Thank you. I got it to go through but it still doesn't do the function I'm looking for. The Risk field doesn't automatically fill in with a word, even after I put the Likelihood and Impact in.

Comment: Take the formula apart and see what you get for the two different parts.